# Summernote add fontsize to toolbar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, wysiwyg

I am trying to add fontsizes to the summernote editor but with no luck.  If I remove `['fontsize', ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '18']],` and use `['fontsize', ['fontsize']],` I get only one size and that is 13.  I am trying to get a list of sizes.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#image_body').summernote({
     toolbar: [
       // [groupName, [list of button]]
       ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
       ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
       //['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
       ['fontsize', ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '18']],
       ['color', ['color']],
       ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
       ['height', ['height']]
     ]
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was I had a file bootstrap.js that was breaking the code.

```
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <!-- include summernote css/js -->
 <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote-lite.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to change the options you have to specify the array in the property `fontSizes`. The code below will display the font button with the options `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `14` and `18`:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  fontSizes: ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '14', '18'],
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});
```

[image]

You can see the editor working [here](https://codepen.io/CaptainIvan/pen/YvXQdx).

Comment: Tried that and still getting nowhere.  Copied your code and nothing.  No js errors nothing.

Comment: Can you give me the part of your code where you call the function also the part where you call the JS files with `<source>`?